# sql server queries related to case statement

Tags: sql

My query like this

case when statement1 = statement2 then offer1

if offer1 is have value means  then i need to display offer1 value will be 'Yes'

How to  write the query for this?

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* - it produces a *value*. It's not a *statement* (statements are things that are a complete unit, by themselves, such as a complete `SELECT ...`)

Comment: `CASE` in SQL is much like the `?` operator in C or Java, if that helps.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? A data sample, your `statement1` & `statement2` things, as well as the expected output for those prerequisites? (Please edit your question and add that information.)

Answer (score 0):

You can nest multiple `CASE` expressions like so:

```
CASE
  WHEN statement1 = statement2 
  THEN 
    CASE WHEN offer1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE ... END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stored procedures and return a value depending on the conditions you need, in the stored procedures you can design your conditions using normal if statements, take a look at this example from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/transactsql/thread/b0e04ea5-59fa-486e-8b76-7f7018b99263):

```
Create procedure dbo.Prc
@Value varchar(50),
@Result bit OUTPUT
AS
Begin
If exists (select 1 from YourTable where Field=@Value)
set @Result=1
Else
set @Result=0
End
```